# How do you close a partial view opened in a pop up and refresh the main page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am using a partial view that is displayed in a pop up to edit the details of a record that is clicked on in the main window.  On this view, the user can edit, delete or cancel.  When the detail record is edited or deleted successfully, I want to close the partial view and update the main window.  Right now, on delete, my main view is reloading in my pop up on success.

Any help getting this to work is greatly appreciated.

The HTML:

```
`<a href="javascript:popup('@Url.Action("EditCaseEmployer/" + item.Id, "CaseOptions")')">@item.StartDate.ToShortDateString()</a>`
```

Here are the custom javascript functions to popup a window:

```
function popup(url) {
window.open(url, 'notes', 'width=900,height=600,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,directories=no,location=no,menubar=no,status=no,left=0,top=0');
}
function popup(url, windowName) {
window.open(url, windowName, 'width=900,height=600,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,directories=no,location=no,menubar=no,status=no,left=0,top=0');
}
```

Comment: Are you using `window.open` to open the popup?

Comment: This is the code in place when I took this over. It can be changed if necessary.  <a href="javascript:popup('@Url.Action("EditCaseEmployer/" + item.Id, "CaseOptions")')">@item.StartDate.ToShortDateString()</a>

Comment: What is `popup`? I wasn't aware that such function exist. Is it custom made? If so, how does it look?

Comment: Can you use a modal (or non-modal) popup div instead of a window? That way, everything is in the same window, and you have full control with javascript.

Comment: @Darin I added the popup definition to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a boolean property to the view model that you are using in your partial:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        ShouldReload = false;
    }
    public bool ShouldReload { get; set; }

    // Some properties
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}
```

and then in the partial test its value and refresh the opener and close the popup:

```
@model MyViewModel

@if (Model.ShouldReload)
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // refresh the parent window
        window.opener.location.reload();

        // close the popup
        window.close();
    </script>
}
else
{
    using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Foo)
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Foo)
        <button type="submit">OK</button>
    }
}
```

Now all that's left are the 2 controller actions that will be used to respectively show the partial and process it:

```
public ActionResult Dialog()
{
    var model = new MyViewModel();
    return PartialView(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Dialog(MyViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // the model is invalid => redisplay the partial
        return PartialView(model);
    }
    // TODO: at this stage the model is valid 
    // => pass it to the service layer for processing

    // everything went fine => set the ShouldReload flag to true
    // so that the view refreshes its opener and closes itself
    model.ShouldReload = true;
    return PartialView(model);
}
```